# Check if application uses only available classes and methods

Tags: android

I have an application that runs on Android 2.1 and higher. But it's compiled with Android 3.1 SDK because it uses some features from this SDK. Recently I received a bug report from the Android Market. The error was about using a method that is not available on current platform. It was [Bundle.getString(String, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

So I'd like to know if there're some tools that can check if an application uses API that is available on a minimal required platform.

**EDIT**: I know that `Bundle.getString(String, String)` is from API Level 12 and I use API Level 7. I just want a tool that will automatically check for such kind of errors.

Comment: where is url that's wrong please correct it

Comment: Indeed, you have to be very careful when you want to enable some newer features like hardware acceleration or supports-screens. You might find the [API Analysis plugin](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/) (scroll down the page) useful - this will tell you when you're using features not available in the minSdkVersion.

Comment: Great, this plugin works. Unfortunately it outputs such errors as warnings but anyways it's better then nothing. If you post this comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

***yes i got it. this is method introduce at 12 api level and you have use it previously.***

[image]

now remove that method  from your code and update your apk.

Comment: Thanks but I know it. I just don't want this problem to be repeated so I'm asking for a tool that will auto-check such errors.